# Extracting data from string

Tags: php, string, extract, explode

I have string that contains area map and some other info:

```
$string = 'something here 
<map name="map">
< area shape="circle" coords="34,210,3" alt="something 1" href="test.php?place=aaa&time=1" />
< area shape="circle" coords="34,220,3" alt="something2" href="test.php?place=bbb&time=2" />
< area shape="circle" coords="669,229,3" alt="some 8" href="test.php?place=bbb&time=3" />
</map>';
```

How can I get coordinates, place and time extracted from string for each area?

Comment: Don't forget to tell us [What you've tried so far](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) and where you're stuck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out, I used regex to extract the variables into an array. You can see the results with the var_dump.

```
$string = 'something here 
<map name="map">
< area shape="circle" coords="34,210,3" alt="something 1" href="test.php?place=aaa&time=1" />
< area shape="circle" coords="34,220,3" alt="something2" href="test.php?place=bbb&time=2" />
< area shape="circle" coords="669,229,3" alt="some 8" href="test.php?place=bbb&time=3" />
</map>';

preg_match_all("/(\d+\,\d+\,\d+)/", $string, $coords);
preg_match_all("/place\=(.*)\&time\=(\d+)/i", $string, $place_time);

var_dump($place_time, $coords);
```

**var_dump() results**

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'place=aaa&time=1' (length=16)
      1 => string 'place=bbb&time=2' (length=16)
      2 => string 'place=bbb&time=3' (length=16)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'aaa' (length=3)
      1 => string 'bbb' (length=3)
      2 => string 'bbb' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '3' (length=1)

array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '34,210,3' (length=8)
      1 => string '34,220,3' (length=8)
      2 => string '669,229,3' (length=9)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '34,210,3' (length=8)
      1 => string '34,220,3' (length=8)
      2 => string '669,229,3' (length=9)
```

You would access the information in the above example by array/key:

```
echo $coords[1][0]; //return: 34,210,3
echo $place_time[1][0]; //return: aaa
echo $place_time[2][0]; //return: 1
```

Comment: You can use `parse_url` and `parse_str` to parse the URL; you will then be able to successfully parse `test.php?time=1&foo=bar&place=aaa`.

Comment: Regex + XML/HTML ===> EVIL. It's nearly as evil as using `eval` -> [Read this!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) ASAP

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Fair enough, but were not matching html here, simply some arbitrary text that happens to be in tags, which even if they were missing would still work. Your solution is good too. Potato-Potato.

Comment: @phpisuber01: I beg to differ, this isn't just some arbitrary text - I'd say we're dealing with XML. The OP might shed some light on who's got the right idea here

Comment: @Elias: stop quoting that answer, please. A string that contains `<` and `>` is not a HTML document.

Comment: @SalmanA: Steady on - I'm just saying what I _think_. Just out of curiosity though: what answer did you think I was quoting? Or are you referring to the link to that Cthulu-thing?

Comment: @Elias: The one the contains gibberish. It does not make sense to me. BTW, I have no objections about using DOMDocument, I just like to keep things simple.

Comment: @SalmanA: That's the point of the guy who posted that answer: _it doesn't make sense_ in his (and my) opinion to use regex on markup. But everybody is entitled to their own opinion, and I understand where you're coming from. Happy Coding

Comment: Hi! This solution works. Also, this has nothing to do with xml; I get that variable from database and it contains area map in addition to other information.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like markup to me, why don't you simply parse it?

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadXML($string);
$areas = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('area');
$coordinates = array();
for ($i = 0, $j = count($areas);$i<$j;$i++)
{
    array_push($areas, $areas[$i]->getAttribute('coords'));
}
```

That's the way you should treat markup, IMO - unless of course you're [looking forward to the end of times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

[See how you can make your life easier when parsing markup](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), that's what the docs are for.

As @SalamanA pointed out, treating a fragment as an entire DOM could be considered overkill. Thankfully, there is such a thing as a [DOMFragment class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocumentfragment.php) which can be used in just such a case.

```
$DOMFragment = new DOMDocumentFragment();
$DOMFragment->appendXML($string);
//or, when you need to treat multiple DOMFragments:
$DOM = new DOMDocument();//can be used as a sort-of DOMFragment factory
$fragment = $DOM->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment2 = $DOM->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML($string);
```

Comment: Kill a bird with cannon? While generally I do not endorse parsing HTML with regex, but using DOMDocument to parse fragments of HTML is sometimes an overkill.

Comment: @SalmanA: Fair enough, I've edited my answer to point out the DOMDocumentFragment object